# Add another line with 3 select menus

Tags: jquery

I have 3 select menus but then when this button is clicked

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</button>
```

I want it to the 3 dropdowns again, how can this be done?

Comment: Add a click handler to that button that appends 3 dropdowns to the DOM.

Comment: Sorry i'm still new to jquery how would one acheive this?

Comment: I don't understand "I want it to the 3 dropdowns again, how can this be done?"

Comment: to show 3 dropdown menus again on clicking the add button.

Answer (score 1):

If you want exactly the same 3 dropdowns to be repeated, maybe you should have a structure like this:

```
<div id="main_container">
    <div class="select_container select_master">
        <select 1 ....
        <select 2 ....
        <select 3 ....
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, provide your button an identifier. If you don't have other buttons with the same classes, then you can just use [one of many ways to do this]:

```
$('.btn .btn-primary .btn-sm').on('click', function() {
    var dropdowns = $('.select_master').clone(true); // true to also clone event handlers
    dropdowns.removeClass('select_master'); // you only need one master
    $('#main_container').append(dropdowns);
});
```